# How to apply dynamic gif file to SKSpriteNode in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a dynamic gif file, which has been dragged to my project, I intend to load it into my scene via code snippet:

```
let pen = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "basketball.gif")

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    pen.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.1)
    addChild(pen)
}
```

But it only shows the static one, not dynamic. Could anyone give me any idea why this can't work? Thanks!

Comment: You will need separate textures to make an animation. Afaik, gif can't be used in SpriteKit...But I haven't tested this. So, initialize textures, then use SKAction.animateWithTextures to animate.

Comment: Interesting,  he says he gets a static image,  so maybe it can be used.  I wonder if it generates indexes textures for us?  My guess will be no, and instead UIImage will convert it to a 32bit image

Comment: It would be easier to just split this gif into PNG frames and attach as a sprite sheet and then animate that.